# Pasar parametros a una URL por medio de POST

Tags: asp.net, post, webforms, web

Por favor quien me colabora con lo siguiente: en un sistema web form que tengo publicado hacia internet, me piden pasarme 3 parametros a un  web form por medio de POST, nunca hice GET o POST en asp.net web form y estoy perdido de como se hace eso, entonces en resumen lo que tendria que hacer es lo siguiente:

> Desarrollar un Web Form que por medio de POST recepcione 3 datos (como hago eso)
>
> Desarrollar un cliente que pase los 3 datos por medio de post.

Les agradezco de antemano, gracias.

Comment: la recepcion por medio de post es tan simple como usar Request.Form["key"] en el Page_Load de aspx, ahora que tipo de cliente te refiere ? es un winform o consola? vas a invocar la pagina usar alguna libreria?

Comment: Si no tienes idea de como comenzar te sugiero ver algunos de los tutoriales que aparecen buscando en Google [tutorial+webforms+asp.net](https://www.google.com.ar/search?q=tutorial+webforms+asp.net&oq=tutorial+webforms&aqs=chrome.1.69i57j0l5.8912j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#q=tutorial+webforms+asp.net&tbs=lr:lang_1es&lr=lang_es) y filtrando por páginas en Español.

Comment: Leandro, el cliente web es un sitio web de un tercero que no se en que plataforma y/o tecnología trabaja, yo tengo que proporcionarle una url que me permita recepcionar parámetros por post en un web form, ahora el cliente que menciono en la pregunta es porque antes de proporcionarle la url al cliente, yo tengo que realizar pruebas y para dichas pruebas necesito desarrollarme un pequeño cliente, ya sea consola, winform o webform, con preferencia webform.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entiendo tiene que invocar la url de un aspx, enviando valores por POST y recibir la respuesta, la cual seria un html.

Si es asi harias uso de la clase `WebClient`

[HTTP POSTs and HTTP GETs with WebClient and C# and Faking a PostBack](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/HTTPPOSTsAndHTTPGETsWithWebClientAndCAndFakingAPostBack.aspx)

importante analiza como define el Method

```
System.Net.WebRequest req = System.Net.WebRequest.Create(URI);

req.Method = "POST";
```

entonces defines parametros que envias en el `GetRequestStream()`

de esta forma podrias crear un cliente que consume el aspx enviando los valores por `POST`

Comment: Gracias Leando.